# Insert multiple actors on the same movie with MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't know how to ask this, I just started to learn PHP and Mysql, and I'm having a lot of trouble doing something that is easy.

Let's say I have two tables in Mysql Actors and Movies.

The Actors have ID and NAME
And the Movies also have the same ID and NAME.

In this example, let's say our actors are 1 Brad Pitt, 2 Edward Norton, and 3, Jack Nicholson

The movies are 1 Fight Club and 2 Ocean's Thirteen.

Brad Pitt and Edward Norton are in Fight Club,
Brad Pitt is on Ocean's Thirteen,
And Jack Nicholson isn't in any of those movies.

How can I link the actors to the movies on my Mysql Database? Also how can I display them using PHP?

I appreciate any help, I am lost in this one! Thanks for your attention!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You can use `JOINS` for this.

In a brief intro, lets have another table, `relations`. In that, the movies and the actors are related. The `PRIMARY KEY` will be the combination of the both `ID`s.

```
Actors Table
+----+----------------+
| ID |           NAME |
+----+----------------+
|  1 |      Brad Pitt |
|  2 |  Edward Norton |
|  3 | Jack Nicholson |
+----+----------------+

Movies Table
+----+--------------------+
| ID |               NAME |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 |         Fight Club |
|  2 | Ocean''s Thirteen. |
+----+--------------------+
```

Now we can have a relationship table with these two IDs.

```
+-------+-------+
| MOVIE | ACTOR |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     1 |
|     1 |     2 |
|     2 |     1 |
+-------+-------+
```

This way, Movie 1 will have both actors 1 and 2.

#### SQL Queries

```
CREATE TABLE Actors (`id` int, `name` varchar(255));

INSERT INTO Actors (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Brad Pitt'),
(2, 'Edward Norton'),
(3, 'Jack Nicholson');

CREATE TABLE Movies (`id` int, `name` varchar(255));

INSERT INTO Movies (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'Fight Club'),
(2, 'Ocean''''s Thirteen.');

CREATE TABLE stars (`movie` int, `actor` int);

INSERT INTO RelationShip (`movie`, `actor`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1);
```

Comment: I created this tables, just changed the name of the Relationship to Movie_actor, and them i tryed this query "SELECT movies.name FROM actors, movies, movie_actor WHERE actors.id = movie_actor.actor = 1  AND movies.id = movie_actor.movie" this returned Fight Club 2 times, and Oceans Thirteen 1 time. Can any of you guys show tell my what is wrong with this query, i was trying to list the Brad Pitt movies!

Comment: movie_actor is a field name, and should come before the `FROM`; table names should come after the `FROM`

Comment: movie_actor is the relationship table, who has the ids of the movies and actors

Comment: shouldn't the above code be - CREATE TABLE RelationShip (`movie` int, `actor` int);

Answer (score 1):

in this case you have a many to many relationship, it means, one actor may be in many movies, and one movie may have many actors.

what you do in this cases is generate an intermediate table, let's say
"MOVIE_ACTOR" which should have 2 columns
MOVIE_ID and ACTOR_ID

this is a good point to start

so, for example i you want to know all the movies from an actor you would do your query something like this:

```
SELECT movies.name FROM movie_actor LEFT JOIN movies ON movie_actor.movie_id = movies.id
WHERE movie_actor.actor_id = (SELECT id FROM actors WHERE name = 'brad pitt')
```

here's how yo could create the table
CREATE TABLE MOVIE_ACTOR (`movie_id` int, `actor_id` int);

```
INSERT INTO MOVIE_ACTOR (`movie`, `actor`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 1),
(2, 2);
```

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need a joining table, `ActorMovieMatch`

This table would have two fields, `ActorID` and `MovieID`, which are foreign keys to the primary key ID's in the other tables.

When updating the database, you would update this table, independently of the other tables.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to set up your table structure.  Here's one that may work for you. I have them in the form of diagrams for readability; you'd have to create MySQL statements for all that.

First, your table types:

```
Movie = ID,Title
Actor = ID,FirstName,LastName
StarredIn = ActorID,MovieID
```

Next the values of your tables:

```
Movie
------------------
1|Fight Club
2|Ocean's Thirteen

Actor
-------------------
1|Brad|Pitt
2|Edward|Norton
3|Jack|Nicholson

StarredIn
---------
1|1
2|1
```

Notice how you simply insert the ids of the entities that are connected in StarredIn.  This is the heart and soul of the relational system.  Data distributed across tables, connected by IDs.  This lets you put any actor as many times as you need to.  It also protects you against things like name changes, if one day Bradd Pitt decides he wants to change his name, the ID still points to the same entity (you'd just modify the actor table).

Also, while not required, you'd want Primary Keys to ensure you don't add any duplicates.  I recommend primary keys on ID for both Movie and Actor and a composite primary Key (ActorID,MovieID) for StarredIn.

As for the PHP part; I recommend reading up on either mysqli or PDO as they tell you how to connect PHP to MySQL.  Here are some links to get you started:

Mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php